# Difference between Microsoft AI Builder and Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, powerapps

I am exploring ways to improve some of our processes and applications using microsoft tools and more specifically the **Custom Vision Cognitive Service**. However, i am getting lost in the MS offerings and the **Preview AI Builder service in PowerApps** which seems to be offering the same capability.

The test that I am trying with both services i using Products pictures and utilize the services to provide me with the **brand, sub-brand and some other specifications on the product**. To start with, i have started with the browser version of the Custom Vision service (not the SDK) which, because it is a non-programmer interface, is really similar to the AI builder.

Has someone more inputs on the **strategy behind the AI Builder in Powerapps and how it complements/replaces some of the capabilities of the MS cognitive services** (and more specifically their browser/non-programmer versions)?

Answer (score 2):

In a few words, tools in PowerApps (like in Microsoft Flow or even Logic Apps) are backed by other (more technical) services provided by Microsoft (or third party).

PowerApps and Flow are solutions designed to be used by non-developer people: understanding the technical behaviour / implementation is not needed.

Using AI Builder service in PowerApps vs Custom Vision: generally, there may be a delay between new technical features and the time they are provided in those tools for example. Some features are also never available in "business" versions.